# Firebase & Swift - Date saved with UTC -7?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand how exactly dates are saved in the CloudFirestore of Firebase...

When I put the current date in the database `dateToSAve = Date()` , this date is stored with UTC-7:

[image]

But in someone in France for example, want to save data on Firebase, it will be the current date -9 hours to conform with the UTC -7

And sometimes, because of that, it can be a different day...
Do you know how to handle this problem? I would like to save in the database, the current date of the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not store date object in database, instead you should save timestamp in UTC 0. And after retrieving that timestamp you can convert it back into date with the time portion in your current time zone.

For getting timestamp in UTC 0:

```
let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

And for converting timestamp back to date with the time portion in your current timezone:

```
// gives date with time portion in UTC 0
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy"  // change to your required format
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

// date with time portion in your specified timezone
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```